# What can cause data written to a TCP socket on windows to be altered before transmiission?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, network-programming, windows-networking

Something is altering data written to TCP sockets on my Windows (Windows 7) machine - specifically, when the bytes follow a specific HTTP POST pattern, the pattern is repeated when the bytes are read from the corresponding listener socket side of the connection.

The following bytes are written to the client socket (note: each line ends with a carriage-return and newline and the two nonblank lines are followed by two blank lines):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

what is read from the listener socket is:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I've tested this on the loopback (127.0.0.1) address on my machine, but I've also seen the modified bytes when the listener socket was on another machine, so it appears the bytes are modified on the client side.  I've reproduced the problem using both netcat and a java program (see below) on my machine, so the issue appears to be in the TCP stack. I've only been able to cause it with a specific set of HTTP headers, so it appears that something is doing deep packet inspection on my TCP communication and altering it.  If I alter the input bytes slightly (e.g. so it is not a valid HTTP request by, for instance, changing "POST" to "QOST", it works fine).

Below is a java program I've written that demonstrates this and its output:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public final class Main {

    private static final String PAYLOAD
        = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            + "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            ;
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static final void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Server());
        serverThread.start();

        final byte[] payloadBytes = PAYLOAD.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int i = 0;
        try (final Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), PORT)) {
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            final OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            for (final byte byteValue : payloadBytes) {
                os.write(byteValue);
                os.flush();
                i++;
            }
        }
        serverThread.join();
        System.out.println("bytes written: " + i);
    }

    private static final class Server implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
//                while (true) {
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                    try (final InputStream is = socket.getInputStream()) {
                        int i = 0;
                        int byteValue;
                        while ((byteValue = is.read()) >= 0) {
                            System.out.print((char) byteValue);
                            System.out.flush();
                            i++;
                        }
                        System.out.println("----------------");
                        System.out.println("bytes read: " + i);
                    }
//                }
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

----------------
bytes read: 96
bytes written: 49
```

Below is the same test using netcat (nc.exe from cygwin) on windows (note: the file test_payload.blob contains the bytes as described above and derived from the PAYLOAD constant in the java program):

start the nc listener:

```
nc -l 8080 > nc_capture; more nc_capture
```

run the nc client (in another shell from the listener):

```
nc -v 127.0.0.1 8080 < test_payload.blob
```

the output written to nc_capture:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


POST / HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

My first thought was a buggy firewall, so I disabled it, but it still happens.  I also tried resetting my winsock and tcp/ip, and it still happens.  I tried disabling all of my network adapters (the above tests work on the loopback IP address, so they are not needed), and it still happens.  At this point, I am pretty much out of ideas, and I don't even know how I would go about trying to debug this at a lower level.  Has anyone ever seen something like this before?  Is there some low level diagnostic tool on windows that I can use to see what might have its hooks into my TCP stack?

Comment: "*the two nonblank lines are followed by two blank lines*" - then you are sending a malformed HTTP request.  The lines that constitute the HTTP headers must be followed by **ONE** blank line, not **TWO**.  The line after the one blank line **MUST** be the start of the body data, in this case the first `chunked` data block.  But you are not sending any chunk at all.  Also, HTTP 1.1 **requires** a `Host` header, which you are also not sending.

Comment: Also, do you have the same problem if you get rid of the `write(int b)` loop on the client and just use a single call to `write(payloadBytes);` (followed by `i += payloadBytes.length`) instead?

Comment: And do you have it if you don't turn off the Nagle algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but whether the HTTP is well formed is irrelevant to the problem - The raw TCP socket should have no knowledge of HTTP.  The problem is that the bytes written to the client socket are not the bytes read from the corresponding socket on the other side.  The original issue I was debugging was dealing with an HTTP request.  However, debugging showed that the TCP bytes themselves were being modified before being sent.  It just happens that this pattern of bytes (which was derived from an HTTP request - perhaps an invalid one) triggers this behavior.

Comment: AV software installed?

Comment: Whether the HTTP is well formed isn't irrelevant if something is doing deep HTTP packet inspection. You don't have any evidence to show that this 'just happens'. The evidence shows the contrary.

Comment: I've tested with and without the nagle algorithm (i.e. setTcpNoDelay()).  I've also written one byte at a time and writing the whole byte[] at once.  It happens in both cases.

Comment: TrendMicro - though as I said, I disabled the firewall...

Comment: EJP - right something appears to be doing deep packet inspection which is why this specific HTTP string seems to trigger it.  I am trying to figure out what it is though and get it to stop.  Also I can't think of any reason it would be beneficial for it to modify TCP data in this way even if it did detect that I was sending malformed HTTP.

Comment: EJP - I didn't follow the second part of your comment about "evidence" that this "just happens".  I have a reproduceable test case on my machine, and I've tested it on at least one other machine where it did not occur.  It appears that there is something (e.g. configuration or system-level 3rd party software (hopefully not malware)) that is causing this behavior on my machine, and I'm looking for help on what tools or system diagnostics I can run to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: You commented that it just happens to be an HTTP packet. I doubt it. The evidence suggests that it *only* happens in HTTP packets, and malformed ones at that. Otherwise nothing would work, including posting to this site. The first thing I would do is fix the malformation and see if that fixes the problem. You have to fix it anyway.

Comment: EJP - Okay, I guess I didn't state that clearly.  What I meant by saying that the test data "happens to be" an HTTP request is just that it should be irrelevant to the TCP sockets fulfilling their contract (i.e. that the bytes written to the sending socket match the bytes read from the receiving socket) that the data has a particular form - there is no application layer code in either of the test cases that should be trying to interpret the HTTP request.  However, triggering this issue most certainly is tied to the specific HTTP like structure of the request.

Comment: EJP - Incidentally, when I remove the second carriage return newline, nothing comes through (though you still may say that is malformed as there is no chunked data).

Comment: In any case, I should be able to send any data through the TCP sockets without it being altered by something that is trying to interpret a layer-7 protocol and altering it.  I'm just trying to figure out what that something is and disable it.

Comment: "*Is there some low level diagnostic tool on windows that I can use ...*": Try Wireshark:  http://www.wireshark.org